# Checking all radiobuttons without Jquery

Tags: javascript, dom

i want to check the first element of multiple radiobutton groups.

I'm using Firebug, which is why i do not want, yes i know there is firequery, but there must be a way like they did it in the old days :)

Any help yould be great, thx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop backwards over `document.getElementsByTagName('input')` and set `checked` to `true` if `type` is equal to `"radio"`.

If you try to check multiple buttons in the same group, the last one will hold.
Thus, looping backwards will end up checking the first option in each group.

Comment: how do i do that? looping backwards sounds exactly like what i need

Comment: `for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: That seems so wrong...and yet, it's so simple and it should work. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Yes; I was proud of that. ☺

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Feeling a bit silly here, you **said** you were using Firebug, and thus Firefox, and so we have `querySelector` available. Thus checking the first radio button in any given group is a one-liner:

```
document.querySelector('input[type="radio"][name="theGroupName"]').checked = true;
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/aciyub)

`querySelector` returns the *first* matching element, and so the above will return the first `input` element with `type="radio"` and `name="theGroupName"`. Then we just set its `checked` to `true`.

Granted that doesn't do the first of *all* groups, but it gives you more control and is (again) a one-liner — handy for Firebug.

---

**Original answer**

You can use [`getElementsByTagName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-A6C9094) to get all `input` elements in document order. Then loop through them, only processing the ones with `type="radio"` and remembering the last `name` you encoutered; mark `checked = true` for the first of each name.

E.g.:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var lastName, index, input;
for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
    input = inputs.item(index);
    if (input.type.toLowerCase() === "radio") {
        if (input.name !== lastName) {
            lastName = input.name;
            input.checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/omijav)

If you want to limit that to some container, you can use the [`element` version of `getElementsByTagName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1938918D).

Comment: Note that this assumes all radio button options will be adjacent in the source (with no intervening radio buttons).